# Create a map out of a grouped array objects

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm using Underscore.js to map a new object array out of an existing object array but cannot really get the desired results.

Essentially I have an object array like:

```
[
  {
    "total": 5.21,
    "number": 3,
    "a": "Paid",
    "y": 2015,
    "m": 1,
    "d": "2015-01-17T23:58:34.115Z"
  },
  {
    "total": 374.65,
    "number": 3,
    "a": "Scheduled",
    "y": 2015,
    "m": 1,
    "d": "2015-01-18T02:16:03.503Z"
  },
  {
    "total": 310.84,
    "number": 1,
    "a": "Paid",
    "y": 2015,
    "m": 1,
    "d": "2015-01-17T23:58:34.115Z"
  },
  {
    "total": 284.41,
    "number": 3,
    "a": "Scheduled",
    "y": 2015,
    "m": 1,
    "d": "2015-01-18T02:16:03.503Z"
  }
]
```

which I would like to map into something like:

```
[
  {
    "key": "Paid",
    "values": [
      [
        "2015-01-17T23:58:34.115Z",
        5.21
      ],
      [
        "2015-01-17T23:58:34.115Z",
        310.84
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "Scheduled",
    "values": [
      [
        "2015-01-18T02:16:03.503Z",
        374.65
      ],
      [
        "2015-01-18T02:16:03.503Z",
        284.41
      ]
    ]
  }
]
```

I've tried using the ._map method returns a map like this ([**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/chridam/frpxegka/)):

```
var mapped_bill = _.map(bill, function(item) {
    return {"key": item.a, "values": [item.d, item.total]}
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(mapped_bill));

/* returns:
[
  {
    "key": "Paid",
    "values": [
      "2015-01-17T23:58:34.115Z",
      5.21
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "Scheduled",
    "values": [
      "2015-01-18T02:16:03.503Z",
      374.65
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "Paid",
    "values": [
      "2015-01-17T23:58:34.115Z",
      310.84
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "Scheduled",
    "values": [
      "2015-01-18T02:16:03.503Z",
      284.41
    ]
  }
]
*/
```

How do I group the resulting map above so that I can achieve the desired map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use two `_.map` methods with `_.groupBy`:

```
var result = _.map(_.groupBy(data, 'a'), function(el, key) {
    return {
        key: key,
        values: _.map(el, function(item) {
            return [item.d, item.total];
        })
    };
});
```

Check the demo below.

```js
var data = [
  {
    "total": 5.21,
    "number": 3,
    "a": "Paid",
    "y": 2015,
    "m": 1,
    "d": "2015-01-17T23:58:34.115Z"
  },
  {
    "total": 374.65,
    "number": 3,
    "a": "Scheduled",
    "y": 2015,
    "m": 1,
    "d": "2015-01-18T02:16:03.503Z"
  },
  {
    "total": 310.84,
    "number": 1,
    "a": "Paid",
    "y": 2015,
    "m": 1,
    "d": "2015-01-17T23:58:34.115Z"
  },
  {
    "total": 284.41,
    "number": 3,
    "a": "Scheduled",
    "y": 2015,
    "m": 1,
    "d": "2015-01-18T02:16:03.503Z"
  }
];

var result = _.map(_.groupBy(data, 'a'), function(el, key) {
    return {
        key: key,
        values: _.map(el, function(item) {
            return [item.d, item.total];
        })
    };
});

pre.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result, null, 4);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
<pre id="pre"></pre>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks @dfsq! Just didn't know how you to combine `._map` and `._groupBy` :)

Answer (score 1):

Going by your history here then it could be assumed this is actually a [mongodb](/questions/tagged/mongodb) question even though you are just looking at the resulting JavaScript object in the question as presented.

So with the structure you mention actually being the members of a MongoDB collection then the answer to produce the the required output would be:

```js
db.mapped.aggregate([
   { "$group": {
       "_id": "$a",
       "values": {
           "$push": {
               "$map": {
                  "input": { "$literal": ["A","B"] },
                  "as": "l",
                  "in": {
                      "$cond": [
                          { "$eq": [ "$$l", "A" ] },
                          "$d",
                          "$total"
                      ]
                  }
               }
           }
       }
   }}
])
```

So the [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operator there processes our "two element array template" provided in the [**`$literal`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/literal/) operator section, and "transposes" the values via the [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) ["ternary"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic) to either produce the element from "$d" where the first "A" element is matched or the element "$total" where the element is not "A" but therefore "B" as the only other logical choice.

Results in mapping an array that has the first elementof the first match and the second element as the other expected value. These can then be provided to [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/), to create and "array of arrays" as requested.

Which produces from your source as a collection:

```js
{
    "_id" : "Scheduled",
    "values" : [
            [
                    "2015-01-18T02:16:03.503Z",
                    374.65
            ],
            [
                    "2015-01-18T02:16:03.503Z",
                    284.41
            ]
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : "Paid",
    "values" : [
            [
                    "2015-01-17T23:58:34.115Z",
                    5.21
            ],
            [
                    "2015-01-17T23:58:34.115Z",
                    310.84
            ]
    ]
}
```

So you didn't need this post processing in JavaScript as you thought you did. Using the operators that are appropriate to match your conditions on the server side [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) is all you need.